# IBDesignable View - need ViewController at design time

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ibdesignable

I'm creating an IBDesignable component so that I can see the component render live in the Xcode storyboard.  The component is simply a composition of other components.  Unfortunately, one of those components requires a UIViewController to function properly.  Yes, bad, but I have no control over it.

The component works fine running in the app, but does not render properly at design time because the UIViewController for that scene is not available.  I have tried

- marching up the responder chain looking for a UIViewController
- creating an IBOutlet on the component and connecting it to the View 
  Controller in the storyboard

Neither of these has worked; the View Controller is always nil.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A UIViewController can not be render in IBDesignable Mode.
You just can IBDesignable in a view staff.

sample:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SMButton: UIButton {


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = 6
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.baseInstagram.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 0.66

        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.baseInstagram

    }


}
```

The sample is a round button with border.

Comment: I fear that you are correct.  I have tested hooking up other controls from the storyboard to the component with the same result.  The live designer just doesn't work with *any* external outlets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the IBDesignable component's surrounding environment can influence the component itself.